# Problems installing Ubuntu on Dell 2950, trying Server 12.04,

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I have tried to install Ubuntu Server multiple times to no avail?  wondering about other things as well?

HDWR Config:  4GB RAM, 4 2-TB drives in Raid 5 Vol configured through Perc5i.

When going through install process, Ubuntu does not seem to see the logical volume, but rather looks at the drives as if it is going to setup software raid?  Isn't this a hardware based array?

Also, grub fails to install at the very end? Not sure why?  Is it the bios limitation and therefore I can only use 1 Hard Drive for the Os and then the rest on a raid-5 array?

Should I be going to Ubuntu 10 LTS instead?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it perhaps would save me lots of time.

Comment: 1) What is the error you get when grub fails to install?  2) Did you set up a HW RAID (e.g. check from the PERCs BIOS) or did you set them up as JBOD?  3) I hope you know the risk of using large drives and RAID5. (If not search for URE).

Comment: "4 2-TB drives in Raid 5" -- Ubuntu is perhaps smart enough to know that this is a bad idea?